# SQL Server 2005 Service Broker behaviour for poison messages

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, service-broker

When creating a Service Broker Queue in SQL 2008 R2, you can specify the POISON_MESSAGE_HANDLING status as ON or OFF. If it's on, as I understand, after 5 consecutive rollbacks of a message, the message is treated as a poison message, and the queue is automatically disabled. The BROKER_QUEUE_DISABLED event is also raised.

In SQL 2005 (and 2008 non-R2), you don't get the option of the POISON_MESSAGE_HANDLING setting. Does SQL 2005 behave the same as 2008 R2 with this setting ON, or this setting OFF, or something different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service Broker had poison message handling since 2005 and always worked the same way: 5 consecutive rollbaks would disable the queue. Eventually the option to disable it was added, but you have to consider that disabling poison message handling is a terrible idea: if you really hit a poison message the system will spin ad-nauseam w/o making progress.

Comment: One good reason to disable it is you have application-level poison message detection. For instance you can move poison messages out of the queue where they can be traced and potentially requeued. But more importantly, the queue can continue to receive and process messages.

Comment: @JosephDaigle: the decision **not** to support that scenario was very explicit. Moving messages into 'error-queue' and continue processing in the context of *exactly once in order streams of messages* (conversations) is a disaster waiting for happen. We had documented brokerage exchange apps that implemented such and resulted  in $+1M business loss due to handling messages out-of-order. Apps can still implement automatic-handling by responding to the QUEUE_DISABLED event notification, but at least if they shoot themselves in the foot is their own code, not the system code.

Comment: You're right. Some systems require _exact once in order_, others can handle things out of order or more than once. I suppose it just depends on the system and requirements.